# Apollo GraphQL - using value returned from the service - promise issue

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I have a `service.ts` that is adding additional data to the one that were previously fetched from Apollo GraphQL. But the data doesn't matter. What matter is - how to grab the returned value?

```
class TestService implements TestServiceInterface {
  public async fetch(): Promise<any> {
    const result = await apolloClient.query({
      query: gql`
        query Query {
          Test{
           test
           }
            }
          }
        }
      `,
    })


    return {
      graphTitle: "Test",
      graph: "LINE",
      
    };
  }
}

export interface TestServiceInterface {
  fetch(): Promise<any>;
}
```

Fetch is done properly, and in my case I couldn't use `useQuery` and I have to fetch the data outside the React component.

**My question is: how to pass the returned value to another .ts file?**
I tried something like:

```
export const TestData = async () => { const dataToSet = await TestService.fetch(); }
```

but the value returned is a promise:

```
Promise {
  "_U": 0,
  "_V": 0,
  "_W": null,
  "_X": null,
}
```

How to resolve it? How to grab the returned value from TestService in another .ts file?

EDIT 1:

```
const test = TestService.fetch()

export const TestService = (async () => {
  return await test
})()
```

gives me almost what I need, but now in the component I receive (and still an error):

```
Promise {   "_U": 0,   "_V": 1,   "_W": Object {  **correct values here** }
```

How to grab the values from inside of the object?

Comment: You will need to `await` the call to the service.

Comment: where exactly? To the returned value?

Comment: Wherever you call `fetch()` on an instance of the service, such as `await testService.fetch()`

Comment: Now I get: `Promise {
  "_U": 0,
  "_V": 1,
  "_W": Object {
 **correct values here**
}`

How to grab things inside of the object?

Comment: Can you describe more clearly what exactly you're trying to accomplish, and where exactly you're calling these functions? I can't tell at this point what exactly you're going for.

Comment: So, to simplify my case:  let say I have an initial state. And I want to set the initialState to whatever is fetched from Apollo GraphQL. Example:
`const test = TestService.fetch()

export const initialState = (async () => {
  return await test
})()`
And I expect initialState to be the object that I am fetching from my backend. Although I still get this weird promise when I `console.log(initialState)`

Comment: I think you need to `await TestService.fetch()`

Comment: `const test = (async () => {
  return await TestService.fetch();
})();`

Still gives the same result: promise with my desired object within `Promise {   "_U": 0,   "_V": 1,   "_W": Object {  **correct values here** }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: not really, cuz my console.log is okay, it's when I try to use it elsewhere it returns the desired object within the promise